# Problem in my EVAL code, discord.py...(my eval code doesn't work)

Tags: python, discord.py, eval

````
@client.command(name='eval')
@commands.is_owner()
async def _eval(ctx, *, cmd):
    result = eval(cmd)
    await ctx.send(f"```{result}```")
````

This was my code. However, when I type:

```
!eval message.author.id
```

there is no response from the bot, and there is no error also.
If you can help me to make a good eval code, your help is appreciated!
Thanks. --DarkWatery

Comment: The code works for me (or not, due to the input leading to an error). Do you maybe have an `on_message event` (if so, you'd have to include `await client.process_commands(message)`)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an `on_message` event in your code. Try to do this for it:

```
   @client.listen('on_message')
    async def on_message_sent(message):
    enter code here
```

So you need to just change that for your on_message function cause it blocks the commands.